# ScrollView nested in TabView reset position to start while changing tab

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, tabview

I'm experimenting with SwiftUI and I found a weird behaviour of ScrollView when nested in a TabView. If I swipe the ScrollView down and then do a slow gesture to swipe to the next tab, it sometimes reset the scrollView Position to the start. I'm not sure how to explain it well so here is a gif:

[image: See example]

I'm trying to understand what cause this and if there is a way to avoid it.
Here is the code I use:

```
var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab,
            content:  {
                ForEach(coreData.pageList, id: \.self) { page in
                if(coreData.pageList[page] == nil) {
                    ProgressView().onAppear(perform: {
                        loadPage(page: page)
                    })
                } else {
                    ScrollView {
                        Text("START OF PAGE ------- -----Page Number: \(page)! This is a very short text made big to simulate scrolling. This is a very short text made big to simulate scrolling. ").font(.system(size: 90))
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Am I missing something simple, is it a bug (with workaround), am I using these views wrong?

Ultimately I just want to have something that look like a page that you swipe right left or right but having the scroll position reset so fast would not be great user experience and doesn't look great

**Edit**: I haven't found any solution yet, but an interesting point: if I put the ProgressView inside the scrollView the scrollview does NOT reset position but the next tab will already be scrolled with the same amount as the previews page. This is equally "bad" if not worse :-(.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put it into separated view (passing all needed parameters), so SwiftUI will see that view not changed and so not rerender it, ie. it should look like

```
if(coreData.pageList[page] == nil) {
    ProgressView().onAppear(perform: {
        loadPage(page: page)
    })
} else {
    DetailsView(page: page)           // << ScrollView inside
}
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion, I tried it just now, but it gives the exact same result :-(